# Tauri - how to open a new file from the native file explorer

Tags: tauri

I'm trying to add a custom menu item "Open"

```rs
.add_item(CustomMenuItem::new("open".to_string(), "Open"))
```

I'm wondering what code I should put in the handler:

```rs
.on_menu_event(|event| match event.menu_item_id() {
    "open" => {
        //what should go here?
    }
```

to have the file explorer pop up and allow the user to choose to open a new file from their finder.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

For tauri v2 there is a plugin, called [tauri-plugin-dialog](https://crates.io/crates/tauri-plugin-dialog), that has all the dialogs needed for file operations, among some others. You can see it in the [documentation](https://beta.tauri.app/features/dialog/) and the [sources](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-plugin-dialog/blob/v2/src/commands.rs).

For tauri v1, which is the likely one you use as v2 is unstable, you can access the dialog straight from the [frontend](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/dialog/). I don't think there's any exposed rust functionality that does it.

So, from the frontend, you can do this (based on the [`dialog.ts`](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/blob/50a3d17/tooling/api/src/dialog.ts#L112) example):

First, allow dialogs from your `tauri.conf.json`:

```json
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
        "dialog": {
          "all": true,
          "ask": true,
          "confirm": true,
          "message": true,
          "open": true,
          "save": true
        }
    }
```

then, you can create some helper functions to call the api:

```js
interface DialogFilter {
  name: string
  extensions: string[]
}

interface OpenDialogOptions {
  title?: string
  filters?: DialogFilter[]
  defaultPath?: string
  multiple?: boolean
  directory?: boolean
  recursive?: boolean
}

async function open(
  options: OpenDialogOptions = {}
): Promise<null | string | string[]> {
  if (typeof options === 'object') {
    Object.freeze(options)
  }
  let res = invokeTauriCommand({
    __tauriModule: 'Dialog',
    message: {
      cmd: 'openDialog',
      options
    }
  })

  return res as any;
}
```

and you now can simply call it:

```js
open()
```

I have tested this code in my [example tauri app](https://github.com/tachyonicbytes/so-answers/blob/76f60ad38a093025fceb0fea35df3bc57e9bffdb/77524788/tauri-app/src/App.tsx#L94), if you want to see a working example.